# Ayuda con serializacion en java

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, serialización

Tengo en el método main:

`cargarDatos()`:Se encarga de meter datos desde un archivo .dat.

`Ventana v=new Ventana()`: Se encarga de abrir una ventana con la que introduces datos. Acaba con un `defaultCloseOperation: close_on_exit`.

`guardarDatos()`: se encarga de guardar los datos que has introducido en la ventana y los guarda en un archivo .dat.

El problema es que el programa no llega a ejecutar la ultima linea porque cuando cierra la ventana termina la ejecución. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Compartenos tu código para poder ayudarte

Comment: muestra el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Imaginando tu código, supongo que si cambias el atributo `defaultCloseOperation` a: `dispose_on_close` evitarás cortar el programa antes de tiempo.